# dereference non-static member functions C++

Tags: c++, binding

Why this statement is wrong?

```
(*std::cout.operator<<) (std::endl);
```

I'm simply calling std :: endl through a late binding ...

Comment: Since when `std::cout.operator<<` gives you a member function pointer?

Comment: Non-static member functions are not functions, as you are just experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

Member functions are always *class* members, not object members. The closest thing to what you're trying to do is this:

```
std::ostream & (std::ostream::* fp)(std::ostream &(*)(std::ostream&))
    = &std::ostream::operator<<;
(std::cout.*fp)(std::endl);
```

That is, you form a *pointer to class member function* `fp` and then invoke the corresponding member function on the `std::cout` object.

Comment: The fun part of this is that you have to write out the entire hideous type so that the compiler can figure out which `operator<<` overload you want :)

Comment: @T.C.: I was mildly pleased with myself for having got that one right on my first attempt...

Comment: Actually, the closest thing to the OP's attempt would be to not have the local variable `fp` and write it all in one line, but that would not fit into this margin: `(std::cout.*????)(std::endl)`.

Comment: `(std::cout.*static_cast<std::ostream & (std::ostream::*)(std::ostream &(*)(std::ostream&))>(&std::ostream::operator<<))(std::endl);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the closest approximation is actually

```
auto lambda = [](auto x){std::cout << x;};
lambda(std::endl);
```

or as a single statement

```
[](auto x){std::cout << x;}(std::endl);
```

Your compiler probably does not support this yet.